vscode static c analyzer gives error when analyzing any file that includes windows.h
When ever I include windows.h when writing C, the analyzer would give me a thousand errors , I could just simply ignore them but the problem is that it won't detect any problem in the code I write
I tried to add arguments to C_Cpp › Code Analysis › Clang Tidy: Args, but it didn't work.
How do I make the analyzer ignore the windows header?
here are the errors for context:
use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_sbb_u32'
use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_sbb_u64'
too few arguments to function call, expected 1, have 0
use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_bsrsi'
definition of builtin function '__rdtsc'
use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_rolqi'; did you mean '__builtin_ia32_crc32qi'?
use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_bsrdi'
definition of builtin function '__lzcnt16'
definition of builtin function '__lzcnt64'
use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_directstoreu_u32'; did you mean '__builtin_ia32_bextr_u32'?
use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_directstoreu_u64'
use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_rdseed_hi_step'
returning 'void' from a function with incompatible result type 'int'
use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_rdseed_si_step'; did you mean '__builtin_ia32_rstorssp'?
use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_rdseed_di_step'
too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 2

I tried to use preprocessors to make clang ignore the code but it caused more problems

An error indicates something is wrong, either with the file or the tool. Please include the complete text of an error in your question

answering this might require version info about your entire toolset
